# How to save results to localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I am new in `HTML` and `jQuery`, and this was my first implementation, and I am not sure it's correct, I need your help, I tried to make simple counter to begin counting per click, and to store the results in  `localStorage`, this is all I could do
but it didn't work, may you tell me what I've done wrong?

Thanks

---

```js
$(function() {
  $('.container li').click(function() {
    var btn = $(this).attr("data-page");
    var element = $('.counter[data-page="' + btn + '"]').html();
    element++
    $('.counter[data-page="' + btn + '"]').html(element);

    localStorage.setItem('save', $('.counter[data-page="' + btn + '"]').html());

    if (localStorage.getItem('save')) {
      $('.counter[data-page="' + btn + '"]').html(localStorage.getItem('save'));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
  <li data-page="facebook">
    <a href="#" class='counter' data-page="facebook">4100</a>
  </li>

  <li data-page="twitter">
    <a href="#" class='counter' data-page="twitter">4100</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: review the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: You need to go more in depth about your issue. From this I personally cannot understand what your issue is? Only issue I can see is you have two counters which save to the same localStorage key which will in turn override one another..

Comment: after reloading the page , the counter resets to the default number however i tried to local storage the results to appear even after reloading but i think it's not correct.

thanks dear

Comment: what i wanted to do is the counter retains the number of clicks even after reloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to init first your buttons with values from localStorage. Then you don't need to retrieve them again, you just need to manipulate the value inside the html and to set the new counter in the localStorage.

Also you need to have one counter by button in your localStorage

```js
// Just to make this snippet work,
// because localStorage is forbiden here

// database = localStorage
database = {
  store: {},
  getItem: function(key) {
    return this.store[key];
  },
  setItem: function(key, val) {
    this.store[key] = val;
  },
}

$(function() {
  $(".counter").each((_, element) => {
    const $btn = $(element);
    const key = `save-${$btn.attr("data-page")}`;
    
    $btn.html(database.getItem(key) || 0);
  });
  
  $(".container li").click(function() {
    const $btn = $(this).find(".counter");
    const key = `save-${$btn.attr("data-page")}`;
    const counter = (+$btn.html()) + 1;

    $btn.html(counter);
    database.setItem(key, counter);
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li data-page="facebook">
    <a href="#" class="counter" data-page="facebook">4100</a>
  </li>

  <li data-page="twitter">
    <a href="#" class="counter" data-page="twitter">4100</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the data from the local storage when the page loads. Right now it only loads after saving, which has no effect.

Each element is also saving to the same part of the local storage, so they will be the same every time the page loads. You need to save to an index based on the data-page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple one:

```
$('.container li').click(function() {
  if (localStorage.count) {
    localStorage.count++
  } else {
    localStorage.count = 1;
  }
})
```

Comment: localstorage has no count  property. This can not work!

Answer (score 0):

Updated script using different variables for different counters. It loads counters values from localStorage or sets them to 0 if not available. It also uses two separate variables to store the values.

I used your code so you can see what is different and what you missed in your solution

```
$(function() {       
  var cntfb = localStorage.getItem('save-facebook');
  $('.counter[data-page="facebook"]').html(cntfb ? cntfb : 0);
  var cnttw = localStorage.getItem('save-twitter');
  $('.counter[data-page="twitter"]').html(cnttw ? cnttw : 0);
  $('.container li').click(function() {
    var btn = $(this).attr("data-page");
    var element = $('.counter[data-page="' + btn + '"]').html();
    element++;
    $('.counter[data-page="' + btn + '"]').html(element);
    localStorage.setItem('save-' + btn, $('.counter[data-page="' + btn + '"]').html());
    if (localStorage.getItem('save-' + btn)) {
      $('.counter[data-page="' + btn + '"]').html(localStorage.getItem('save-' + btn));
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with one more solution https://jsfiddle.net/thrh78u0/

```js
$(function() {
  $('.container li').click(function() {
    var btn = $(this).attr("data-page");
    var element = $('.counter[data-page="' + btn + '"]').html();
    element++
    $('.counter[data-page="' + btn + '"]').html(element);

    localStorage.setItem('save' + btn, element);

    if (localStorage.getItem('save')) {
      $('.counter[data-page="' + btn + '"]').html(localStorage.getItem('save'));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
  <li data-page="facebook">
    <a href="#" class='counter' data-page="facebook">4100</a>
  </li>

  <li data-page="twitter">
    <a href="#" class='counter' data-page="twitter">4100</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this will help you.